# Stripe Start Date

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

How do you set the start date for a subscription? Many of our customers began using our service a few days before we could collect their payment information so we'd like to charge them for these additional days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that the Subscriptions API supports today. You would need to charge your customer the full amount and then put them on a trial period until their next billing date.

The flow would look like this:

1. [Create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) a Customer with the card token
2. [Create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) an invoice item for the plan amount
3. [Create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) a subscription and set them on a trial period until their next billing date using `trial_end`

The last step will create an invoice for the trial, automatically pull the pending invoice item into the invoice and charge the customer for that amount. Then, they won't be charged until the date you set in `trial_end` and each month moving forward on that date.

Comment: Is there any way to set the invoice from the dashboard or can you only do this programmatically?

Comment: @Will you can add invoice items in the dashboard yes it's just a click on the customer